# Why won't JavaScript optimizers perform Common Subexpression Elimination?

Tags: javascript, optimization, compiler-construction

According to [this test](http://jsperf.com/common-subexpression-elimination), seems like manually optimizing for Common Subexpression Elimination makes a function much faster than not doing so, suggesting the optimizer is not doing it itself.

Why?

Comment: Why should we assume a brower's compiler would do that? It might be perfectly fine for the purely functional `Math.tan`, but for other expressions you could easily change the meaning of the program.

Comment: try `Math.random()` instead of `tan()` ;)

Comment: @thg435 sure but shouldn't it be fundamental to tag `tan` and such as referentially transparent?

Comment: @Viclib: Nope, the developer should do that and use `cached` as you did. Telling whether a function is side-effect-free is a non-trivial task…

Comment: I think the answer will nail down to "*Optimizers don't do it until you find one that does. It hasn't been implemented yet because a) the devs didn't have the time and/or b) the profits don't outperform the costs*"

Comment: @Viclib: yes, I wish there were the `pure` keyword in javascript, as in `pure function foo() { no side effects here }` - but there's none.